# Filter method is behaving unexpectedly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, type-hinting, pylance, pyright

I'm trying to introduce type hints into an existing codebase, but I'm running into an issue when I attempt to type my query.

```
from sqlalchemy.orm.query import Query

class DbContext:
    def __init__(self, db_host, db_port, db_name, db_user, db_password):

        engine = create_engine(...)

        session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.Session: Session = session(bind=engine)

...

def fetch(context: DbContext, filters: ...):
    sub_query: Query = context.Session.query(...)
```

Before I added type hints, filtering dynamically was simply a matter of:

```
if filters.name is not None:
    sub_query = sub_query.filter(
        Person.name.ilike(f"%{filters.name}%"))
```

However, now with hinting I'm getting this error:

> Expression of type "None" cannot be assigned to declared type "Query"

Sure enough, `filter` appears to return `None`:

> (method) filter: (*criterion: Unknown) -> None

I navigated to [the source](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/rel_1_3_18/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L1832) and it appears the method does indeed not return anything.

```
def filter(self, *criterion):
    for criterion in list(criterion):
        criterion = expression._expression_literal_as_text(criterion)

        criterion = self._adapt_clause(criterion, True, True)

        if self._criterion is not None:
            self._criterion = self._criterion & criterion
        else:
            self._criterion = criterion
```

There's obviously a disconnect somewhere, as assigning `None` to `sub_query` should result in an error which the hint is warning against, but I need to perform the assignment for the filtering to actually work:

```
# Does NOT work, filtering is not applied
if filters.name is not None:
  sub_query.filter(
               Person.name.ilike(f"%{filters.name}%"))

# Works but Pylance complains
if filters.name is not None:
  sub_query = sub_query.filter(
               Person.name.ilike(f"%{filters.name}%"))
```

This is my first foray into Python, would love some guidance as to what is going on here!

Comment: If you're talking about PEP 484 support, it hasn't been implemented yet because thus far SQLAlchemy has continued to support Python 2.7. SQLAlchemy 1.4 is intended to facilitate the transition from SQLA 1.3 and SQLA 2.0, with the latter dropping support for Python 2.7 and most likely supporting PEP 484.

Comment: Ah, good to know. I'm just scratching my head that `sub_query = sub_query.filter(...)` would seem to assign `None` to `sub_query`, but that obviously isn't happening as subsequent calls to `sub_query.filter` don't result in an exception - by the way the code is running, `filter` would appear to be returning a `Query`

Comment: Iirc `Query.filter` is decorated with the `_generative` decorator. It creates the copy, passes it to `filter()`, and returns it. Just as a "why it works". Since you say you're new to Python, you can read about decorators for example here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators.

Comment: Appreciate the education!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing two things:

- You need to install [*typing stubs*](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/master/docs/type-stubs.md) for SQLAlchemy.
- The `Query.filter()` method has a decorator that defines what is returned.

### Typing stubs for SQLAlchemy

You want to install the [`sqlalchemy-stubs` project](https://pypi.org/project/sqlalchemy-stubs/), it provides stubs for the SQLAlchemy API.

Note that *even with this stub installed* you still will see issues with Pyright (the checking tool underpinning the Pylance extension), because static stubs cannot fully represent the dynamic nature of some parts of the SQLAlchemy API, such as model column definitions (e.g. if your `Person` model has a column called `name`, defined with `name = Column(String)`, then the stubs can't tell Pyright that `name` will be a string). The `sqlalchemy-stubs` project includes a plugin for the *mypy* type checker to handle the dynamic parts better, but such plugins can't be used with other type checkers.

With the stubs installed, Pylance can tell you about `filter`:

[image: Visual Studio code screenshot with Query.filter intellisense information window]

### `Query.filter()` decorator details

The `Query.filter()` method implementation is not actually operating on the original instance object; it has been annotated with a [decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator):

```py
    @_generative(_no_statement_condition, _no_limit_offset)
    def filter(self, *criterion):
        ...
```

The `@_generative(...)` part is significant here; the [definition of the decorator factory](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/be2f4fbf0ee270f504d65c56754608c4d0874125/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/base.py#L219-L230) shows that the `filter()` method is essentially replaced by this *wrapper method*:

```py
    def generate(fn, *args, **kw):
        self = args[0]._clone()
        for assertion in assertions:
            assertion(self, fn.__name__)
        fn(self, *args[1:], **kw)
        return self
```

Here, `fn` is the original `filter()` method definition, and `args[0]` is the reference to `self`, the initial `Query` instance. So `self` is replaced by calling [`self._clone()`](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/be2f4fbf0ee270f504d65c56754608c4d0874125/lib/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py#L545-L549) (basically, a new instance is created and the attributes copied over), it runs the declared assertions (here, `_no_statement_condition` and `_no_limit_offset` are such assertions), before running the original function *on the clone*.

So, what the `filter()` function does, is *alter the cloned instance in place*, and so doesn't have to return anything; that's taken care of by the `generate()` wrapper. It is this trick of swapping out methods with utility wrappers that confused Pyright into thinking `None` is returned, but with stubs installed it knows that another `Query` instance is returned instead.